# Gremlin Spark Java Maven Project - Slow query response

Tags: java, apache-spark, gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I have wrote a program in order to perform some queries on top of Gremlin (I use Janus Graph with Cassandra and Solr as the engine) with the help of Spark, but the query result is terrible slow.

Most probably I have setup something not correctly.

Here is the code I have used.

Driver program:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory;

public class SimpleApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration config = GraphTraversalProvider.makeLocal();
        Graph hadoopGraph = GraphFactory.open(config);


        Long totalVertices = hadoopGraph.traversal().withComputer(SparkGraphComputer.class).V().count().next();
        System.out.println("IT WORKED: " + totalVertices);


        hadoopGraph.close();

    }
}
```

GraphTraversalProvider class

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.Constants;

public class GraphTraversalProvider {

    private static final String KEY_SPACE = "janusgraph";
    private static final String CASSANDRA_ADDRESS = "localhost";

    public static Configuration makeLocal() {
        return make(true);
    }

    public static Configuration makeRemote() {
        return make(false);
    }

    private static Configuration make(boolean local) {

        final Configuration hadoopConfig = new BaseConfiguration();

        hadoopConfig.setProperty("gremlin.graph", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_GRAPH_READER, "org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.cql.CqlInputFormat");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_GRAPH_WRITER, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat");

        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_JARS_IN_DISTRIBUTED_CACHE, true);
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_INPUT_LOCATION, "none");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_OUTPUT_LOCATION, "output");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_SPARK_PERSIST_CONTEXT, true);


        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend", "cql");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hostname", CASSANDRA_ADDRESS);
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.port", "9042");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cassandra.keyspace", KEY_SPACE);


        hadoopConfig.setProperty("cassandra.input.partitioner.class", "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("cassandra.input.widerows", true);

        if (local) {
            hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.master", "local[*]"); // Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.
        } else {
            hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.master", "spark://ADD_YOUR_URL");
        }
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.executor.memory", "2g");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.SPARK_SERIALIZER, "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoRegistrator");


        hadoopConfig.setProperty("storage.hostname", CASSANDRA_ADDRESS);
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace", KEY_SPACE);


        return hadoopConfig;
    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ibc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sparkdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <janus.version>0.5.1</janus.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.0</spark.version>
        <gremlin.version>3.4.6</gremlin.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-solr</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GREMLIN -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>${gremlin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>${gremlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPARK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The output is the following:

```
23:36:29,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
23:36:29,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
23:36:29,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
23:36:29,710 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@704d6e83 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
23:36:30.225 [main] WARN  o.a.t.g.s.p.c.SparkGraphComputer - class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat does not implement PersistResultGraphAware and thus, persistence options are unknown -- assuming all options are possible
23:36:30.516 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Your hostname, nchristidis-GL502VMK resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.12 instead (on interface wlp3s0)
23:36:30.516 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
23:36:32.191 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  o.a.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23:36:33.279 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  o.a.t.g.s.p.c.SparkGraphComputer - HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS is not set -- proceeding regardless
23:36:35.266 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil - Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, but epoll is not available. Using NIO instead.

IT WORKED: 43
23:39:32.111 [Thread-3] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Ignoring Exception while stopping SparkContext from shutdown hook
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrapConfig;
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.close(TransportServer.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1615)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)

Process finished with exit code 123
```

So I get the correct output: `IT WORKED: 43` 43 are the total vertices, but it takes too long.

Also this log message:

```
23:36:33.279 [SparkGraphComputer-boss] WARN  o.a.t.g.s.p.c.SparkGraphComputer - HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS is not set -- proceeding regardless
```

highlights that most probably I have not setup something correctly.

**=================================================================**

**Update: Tuesday, 27th of October**

By submitting the program to a spark cluster with one slave node, and not running it via IDE locally, I have a significant drop from 6 minutes to 3 minutes.

[image]

Comment: how long is it taking?

Comment: @stephenmallette it is taking around 6 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OLAP based Gremlin traversals will be much slower than standard OLTP traversals even for small datasets. There is considerable cost just in getting Spark primed up to process your traversal. That overhead alone might easily give your OLAP query a 1 minute handicap over OLTP. In the comments to your question you explained that your query is taking around six minutes. That does seem a bit on the long side but maybe in the realm of normal for OLAP depending on your environment??

Some graph will optimize for an OLAP `count()` and get you a pretty speedy result but you tagged this question with "JanusGraph" so I don't think that applies here.

You typically don't see the value of OLAP based traversals until you start concerning yourself with large scale graphs. Compare counting 100+ million edges in OLAP versus OLTP and you probably won't mind waiting six minutes for an answer at all (as OLTP might not finish at all).

It's hard to say what you might do to make your current setup faster as you are really just proving things work at this point. Now that you have a working model, I would suggest that the next step would be to generate a significantly larger graph (10 million vertices maybe) and try your count again with a decent sized spark cluster.

Comment: To be honest, I believe that I have some problem there, 6 minutes for a graph consisting of 43 vertices and around 60 edges is too much, the only thing I get during the run of the project from my IDE is the following:

13:31:39.394 [JanusGraph Cluster-nio-worker-1] WARN  c.d.driver.core.RequestHandler - Query '[4 bound values] SELECT column1,value,writetime(value) AS writetime,ttl(value) AS ttl FROM janusgraph.system_properties WHERE key=:key AND column1>=:sliceStart AND column1<:sliceEnd LIMIT :maxRows;' generated server side warning(s): Read 14 live rows and 1852 tombstone cells for...

Comment: 6 minutes does seem long, but i was just trying to point out that if you were expecting millisecond response times from OLAP because the graph was small then that was the wrong assumption. i saw you also have a post on gremlin-users, perhaps you should also post something more about your environment there (is everything running on a single machine, if so how powerful is that? if not a single machine, then what does that environment look like). HadoopMarc is smart about these things - he can help. in reference for others: https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/GJ0OQ3csgHw/m/Bm-LE5kEBAAJ

Comment: Hello again, and deeply thank you for your fast response, I have updated the question, now when I submit the job to a Spark cluster with one slave node instead of running it locally via my IDE, the total execution of time is 3 minutes instead of 6, is that more normal?

Comment: I don't think I've ever tried to measure OLAP performance this way but I'd guess 1 to 3 minutes might be expected (though 3 still seems on the longer end to me for some reason - I'd let HadoopMarc be the final answer on that - he does much more with JanusGraph than I do). i suppose the point I'll make again is that when it comes to evaluating performance, I'd usually be in a position where I was thankful that I got a 6 minute query with OLAP because the query I'd be comparing it to in OLTP would be busy taking the age of the universe to complete :)

Comment: Okay, will wait for his feedback in gremlin-users group.

Yes, I run it on a single machine with 8-cores and 24gb ram, so it should be sufficient for some medium heavy duty things.

What I will try, is to populate the database with a lot of edges and vertices and re-execute the job, and see the time execution.

Comment: just a question that came to my mind, do I need to run a local single node hadoop cluster for OLAP queries? because at the moment I don't.

Maybe that is the case of the slow response time?